# unexpected keyword argument 'min_col' error copying worksheet openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I tried copying a worksheet within the same excel file and I got this error:

```
newWs = wb.copy_worksheet(wb['Sheet1'])
newWs.title = 'NewSheet'
```

```
   newWs = wb.copy_worksheet(wb['Sheet1'])
 File "H:\ocmAppVenv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 419, in copy_worksheet
   cp.copy_worksheet()
 File "H:\ocmAppVenv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\copier.py", line 41, in copy_worksheet
   self.target.merged_cells = copy(self.source.merged_cells)
 File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\copy.py", line 84, in copy
   return copier(x)
 File "H:\ocmAppVenv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\cell_range.py", line 503, in __copy__
   n.ranges.append(copy(r))
 File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\copy.py", line 84, in copy
   return copier(x)
 File "H:\ocmAppVenv\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\cell_range.py", line 148, in __copy__
   return self.__class__(min_col=self.min_col, min_row=self.min_row,
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_col
```

Does anyone know why this error would occur?